# Tenho uma duvida de como posso somar cada item de 2 listas e jogar o resultados da soma para uma terceira em python

Tags: python, lista, append

Estou com o seguinte programa

```py
#Faça um programa  que percorra duas listas e gere uma terceira sem elementos repetidos.

x = []

y = []

z = []

while True:

    n = int(input("digite um número(0 sai): "))

    if n == 0:

        break

    x.append(n) and y.append(n + 1)

c = x[x] + n[x] 

#aqui sai a falha com TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list


while c < len(z):

    z = [c]

    print(z[x])

    c += 1
```

minha duvida é como faço para somar cada item das listas x e y, após isso adicionar esses itens na lista z, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score -2):

Você quer somar os elementos das duas listas e colocar o resultado em uma terceira ou você quer juntar os elementos das duas listas em uma terceira sem repetir?

Caso 1 (somar):

```
x=[1,3,4]
y=[1,2,3]
z=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
      z.append(x[i]+y[i])
```

Resultado:

```
z=[2,5,7]
```

Caso 2 (juntar):

```
x=[1,3,4]
y=[1,2,3]
z=x+y
z=list(dict.fromkeys(z))
print(z)
```

Resultado:

```
z=[1,3,4,2]
```

Isso satisfaz sua dúvida?

Comment: seria isso mesmo, o exercício como está pra mim não necessariamente especifica se eu preciso somar ou concatenar as 2 ambas as forma como não tem algo exato acredito que funcionam, obrigado