# Problema com programa que percorra duas listas e gere uma terceira sem elementos repetidos

Tags: python, lista, loop, condição, append

Por um pouco mais de uma semana eu estive tentando resolver o seguinte exercício: "**Faça um programa que percorra duas listas e gere uma terceira sem elementos repetidos.**" O enunciado em questão faz parte do Exercício 6.3 do livro "*Introdução à programação com Python*" do Professor Nilo Menezes.

A ideia do problema apresentado é que o programador crie um algoritmo que leia duas listas diferentes e que uma terceira lista seja produzida com base nessas duas, ignorando os elementos repetidos e/ou já incluídos na nova lista. Como se trata de um exercício que visa a prática de lógica da programação utilizando os novos conceitos aprendidos, **ele deve ser resolvido sem a utilização de funções.**

Devido a esse importante detalhe, a resolução apresentada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/517165/tenho-uma-duvida-de-como-posso-somar-cada-item-de-2-listas-e-jogar-o-resultados) não se aplica de forma alguma, tampouco o propósito do exercício é o mesmo do [link de redirecionamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309189/soma-de-cada-elemento-de-duas-listas).

O próprio Prof. Nilo já postou a [resolução desse mesmo exercício em seu blog](https://python.nilo.pro.br/exercicios3/capitulo%2006/exercicio-06-03.html), mas com uma lógica significativamente diferente do que venho tentado: **optei por adicionar os elementos da lista 1 e da lista 2 à lista 3 de maneira independente, verificando se há elementos repetidos de cada lista na lista 3 e, em caso negativo, realizando a adição**. Devido a esse fator, meu código se encontra incompleto, tendo sido escrito até a primeira lista, já que o problema se encontra em seu respectivo laço.

Não consigo dizer o que há de errado: após inserir os valores nas variáveis, o programa simplesmente para de ser executado, sem ser encerrado pelo interpretador. Até pensei que poderia ser um problema de sintaxe, mas nesse caso pensei que alguma mensagem seria exibida e o programa seria encerrado corretamente, certo?

Como comentei em um parágrafo acima, **creio que o problema esteja no segundo laço aninhado**.

Segue abaixo o meu algoritmo:

```
# Faça um programa que percorra duas listas e gere uma terceira sem elementos repetidos.

lista_1 = []
lista_2 = []
op = ''
while op != 0:
    op = int(input(f'Digite um termo da lista 1 (0 para parar): '))
    if op != 0:
        lista_1.append(op)
    else:
        op = ''
        while op != 0:
            op = int(input(f'Digite um termo da lista 2 (0 para parar): '))
            if op != 0:
                lista_2.append(op)

indice_lista_1 = 0
indice_lista_2 = 0

lista_3 = []
indice_lista_3 = 0

while indice_lista_1 < len(lista_1):

    while indice_lista_3 < len(lista_1):
        if len(lista_3) == 0:
            lista_3.append(lista_1[indice_lista_1])  # len(lista_3) torna-se igual a 1
        else:
            if lista_1[indice_lista_1] != lista_3[indice_lista_3]:
                lista_3.append(lista_1[indice_lista_1])
                indice_lista_3 = indice_lista_3 + 1

    indice_lista_1 = indice_lista_1 + 1

print(f'A lista 1 é igual a {lista_1}')
print(f'A lista 3 é igual a {lista_3}')


lista_3 = []
```

Também possuo outro rascunho de uma tentativa minha menos atual. Não inclui aqui porque não achei relevante, mas por favor me sinalize caso achar necessário.

Comment: Não pude deixar que a pontuação da minha pergunta caiu. Por favor, me indiquem onde posso melhorar minha dúvida para torna-la mais clara e útil a todos.

Comment: Sei que é um exercício e provavelmente querem que vc faça tudo manualmente, mas só pra constar, em Python vc pode usar `set`, que é uma estrutura que não permite elementos duplicados, então bastaria fazer `terceira = list(set(primeira + segunda))`. E para imprimir, uma forma mais idiomática seria `for i, n in enumerate(terceira): print(f"{i}: {n}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tentei deixar da forma mais simples possivél. Primeiro  são comentários  sobre o seu código / problema, a sequência  que ele faz e por que ele não  está funcionando.

#Da criação de índices  para cima (adição de lista 1 é 2) está  tudo okay.

#No primeiro IF o Len de 3 é 0 logo ele será inicializado e o pelo que você passou a lista 3 irá receber o índice 0 da lista 1 que tem x elementos.

#Exemplo : Se a lista um era ls_1 = [1,2,3] a lista 3 sera ls_3 = [1], por conta do primeiro if.

#Logo após essa mudança ser feita esse primeiro If deixa de ser válido  pois agora a lista 3 tem len() != 0.

#A partir de agora o Else irá rodar, mas tem um problema, o indice [0] de lista um será sempre igual ao indice [0] da lista 3 logo o IF do seu else não pode rodar ,o que está causando um loop infinito, mesmo que não apareça nada na tela. Para verificar basta por um print("Alguma coisa") dentro do seu Else e executar o programa.

#Mas e aquela mudança no indice 1 lá embaixo ??? Bom, ela validaria e quebraria esse loop, porém foi colocada no "escopo", identação dentro do primeiro while e não do segundo, e como é o segundo que está rodando então nunca termina, pois o indice de lista 1/3 não muda.

...Meu código...

```
lista_1 = list()
lista_2 = list()
lista_3 = list()

while True:
num = int(input("Adicionar a lista 1 : "))

if num == 0:
    break       
else:
    lista_1.append(num)     
print()

while True:
num = int(input("Adicionar a lista 2 :"))

if num == 0:
    break
else:
    lista_2.append(num)
```

#Aqui estou fazendo a filtragem das listas por meio de um loop for e uma condicional if, um e dois,

#todos os itens da lista_1 são jogados para o x e passam de um por um na condição if até que não reste mais nenhum item a ser passado.
#Caso o número não esteja presente na lista 3 ele será adicionado.
#Depois o mesmo processo é realizado com a lista 2.

```
for x in lista_1:
if x not in lista_3:
    lista_3.append(x)

for x in lista_2:
  if x not in lista_3:
    lista_3.append(x)
        
print(f"\n{lista_3}")
```

Comment: Veja esse tópico [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) talvez o ajude com a apresentação visual do seu conteúdo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! E perdão pela demora no retorno. Não entendi muito bem a parte em que você comentou de os dois while serem iguais. Com a sua analise resolvi fazer um teste: adicionei um "else: break" no laço que ficava em loop infinito e aparentemente tudo está funcionando, por isso minha dúvida. Em que os while são iguais exatamente?

Comment: peço perdão eu me equivoquei quando analisei os dois whiles, eles são diferentes e meio que resolvi a sua questão no meio da madrugada, acontece. Ps : bem vindo ao python :)